# How to get activate device in X509 self assigned Device type in Azure IOT hub?

Tags: node.js, azure, iot, x509certificate, azure-iot-hub

I am new to IOT and X509 Authentication provisioning.

I am able to register device using node.js in Azure IOT hub (Self Assigned X509 Device type).

The pipeline is,

```
1. Download certificate of the registered device type.
2. convert into key and cert pem files
3. pass register id as device id
```

register_X509.js

```
'use strict';

var fs = require('fs');

var Client = require('azure-iot-device').Client;
var Message = require('azure-iot-device').Message;

var X509AuthenticationProvider = require('azure-iot-device').X509AuthenticationProvider;
var Protocol = require('azure-iot-device-mqtt').Mqtt;


var Transport = require('azure-iot-provisioning-device-mqtt').Mqtt;

var X509Security = require('azure-iot-security-x509').X509Security;
var ProvisioningDeviceClient = require('azure-iot-provisioning-device').ProvisioningDeviceClient;

var provisioningHost = 'my-provisioning-host';
var idScope = 'id-scope';

var registrationId = 'registration-id';
var deviceCert = {
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem').toString(),
  key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem').toString()
};


var transport = new Transport();
var securityClient = new X509Security(registrationId, deviceCert);
var deviceClient = ProvisioningDeviceClient.create(provisioningHost, idScope, transport, securityClient);

// Register the device.  Do not force a re-registration.
deviceClient.register(function(err, result) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("error registering device: " + err);
  } else {
    console.log('registration succeeded');
    console.log('assigned hub=' + result.assignedHub);
    console.log('deviceId=' + result.deviceId);

    var client = Client.fromAuthenticationProvider(X509AuthenticationProvider.fromX509Options(
      result.deviceId, result.assignedHub, deviceCert
    ), Protocol);
    var connectCallback = function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Could not connect: ' + err.message);
      } else {
        console.log('Client connected');
        // Create device Twin
        client.getTwin(function (err, twin) {
          if (err) {
            console.error('could not get twin');
          } else {
            console.log('twin created');

            console.log('twin contents:');
            console.log(twin.properties);

            // Send Event message
            setTimeout(function () {
              var data = JSON.stringify({
                'did':  result.deviceId,
                'dts':  new Date().toISOString(),
                'desiredStatus':  'Activated',
                'reportedStatus':  'Activating',
                'msg': []
              });
              var message = new Message(data);
              console.log('Sending message: ' + message.getData());
              client.sendEvent(message, printResultFor('send'));
            }, 1000);

          }
        });

        client.on('error', function (err) {
          console.error(err.message);
        });

        client.on('message', function (msg) {
          console.log('Id: ' + msg.messageId + ' Body: ' + msg.data);
          // When using MQTT the following line is a no-op.
          client.complete(msg, printResultFor('completed'));
          // The AMQP and HTTP transports also have the notion of completing, rejecting or abandoning the message.
          // When completing a message, the service that sent the C2D message is notified that the message has been processed.
          // When rejecting a message, the service that sent the C2D message is notified that the message won't be processed by the device. the method to use is client.reject(msg, callback).
          // When abandoning the message, IoT Hub will immediately try to resend it. The method to use is client.abandon(msg, callback).
          // MQTT is simpler: it accepts the message by default, and doesn't support rejecting or abandoning a message.
        });
      }
    };
    client.open(connectCallback);
  }
});

// Helper function to print results in the console
function printResultFor(op) {
  return function printResult(err, res) {
    if (err) console.log(op + ' error: ' + err.toString());
    if (res) console.log(op + ' status: ' + res.constructor.name);
  };
}
```

At the end of this output, my device is registed under IOT hub and I am able to make connection as well using following code.

The output of the above script is,

> registration succeeded
>
> assigned hub=my-end-point.net
>
> deviceId=my-device-id
>
> Client connected
>
> twin created
>
> twin contents:null: Object {reported: Object, desired: Object}
>
> Sending message: {"did":"my-device-id","dts":"2020-01-30T07:18:38.471Z","desiredStatus":"Activated","reportedStatus":"Activating","msg":[]}
>
> send status: MessageEnqueued

it says messages is in queue but I am unable to activate the device.

I'm stuck at this stage, Can anyone help me to get rid of this?

any idea why it's not working or Am I going in the right approach would be welcome.

Comment: what do you mean by this "but I am unable to activate the device"? Sounds like the message was sent to IoT Hub alright. From that point you should be able to receive the message on the built-in Event Hub endpoint of IoT Hub

Comment: Yeah, the message was not sent. I'll.try to receive the message. Btw, any hint why I'm unable to send the messages?

Comment: @silent - I tried to receive message I am able to receive the message also. I think the message has been sent to the IOT hub. I guess, It's just in queue and waiting for something.